# How to Calculate pose of a component quickly

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

I'm newbie in gazebo simulator. I'm little confused how to fill the exact value for < pose > tag of link.
Is there any simple way to do it? I looked for pose calculation around but no deep answer.

Please help me. Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6525/how-to-calculate-pose-of-a-component-quickly/) by [RoboTN](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/863/robotn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ahh, the current method to calculate the pose of each link is cumbersome. The pose of each model is in the global frame, and the pose of each link is in the model frame. You currently have to calculate the poses by hand.

Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/66) to make pose calculations a bit easier.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboTN](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/863/robotn/) on 2014-07-03**:
Thanks so much for your answer!